# Why is the hover effect targeting child being overridden when I apply a 'transform scale' to the parent element?

Tags: drop-down-menu, nested, hover, css-transforms

Below is a drop-down list nested in a drop-down list. the first code snippet works just fine; as I hover over the parent of the first drop-down list it's height transitions and it displays as I intended, as with the subsequent nested drop-down list.

The problem is with the second snippet...

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: hsla(33,25%,75%,1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-container a {
    background: lightskyblue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 500ms, height 500ms, color 500ms;
}

.flex-container a:hover {
    background: cornflowerblue;
    color: snow;
}

.flex-container li:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
}

.flex-container ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-container > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

ul li ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}

ul li li {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
li:hover > ul > li {
    height: 45px;
}

/*
ul li li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <title>Page 2</title>
        <meta charser="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Page2.html">Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Page2.html">Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Page2.html">Two</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Page2.html">two</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Page2.html">two</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I make one change at the very bottom of the CSS as I wanted the hover effect to be just a bit more pronounced. I apply a transform scale effect to the dropdown list's li's.

The first drop-down list works just fine, but then the second drop-down list does not.

Can someone please explain what is happening?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: hsla(33,25%,75%,1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-container a {
    background: lightskyblue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 500ms, height 500ms, color 500ms;
}

.flex-container a:hover {
    background: cornflowerblue;
    color: snow;
}

.flex-container li:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
}

.flex-container ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-container > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

ul li ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}

ul li li {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}
li:hover > ul > li {
    height: 45px;
}

ul li li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <title>Page 2</title>
        <meta charser="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Page2.html">Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Page2.html">Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="Page2.html">Two</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Page2.html">two</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Page2.html">two</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I don't understand why the problem occurred in the first place, nor do i understand why the fix I found works but it does.

I simply made the overflow property 'visible' in the (ul li li:hover ) and it works.